# Setting password expiration date for specific local account in Windows

Tags: windows, user-accounts

Is it possible to set password expiration date for one local account in Windows? 
It's possible to set account policy with `net accounts /maxpwage` command, but I'm interested in changing the date for one specific account, without making changes to the policy or other accounts.

The `net user <logonname>` command can show the expiration date for the account given in *Password Expires:* field, but it seems like you cannot change it with any `net user` switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password expiration is a global site setting and cannot be set only
for a single account.

The most you can do is to set the account to have a password that expires
or does not expire, all according to the site expiration policy.

If you are looking for a command-line tool, this is the
[wmic command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmic),
and the syntax is:

```
wmic UserAccount where Name="user name" set PasswordExpires=True
```

For more information see:

- [Enable or Disable Password Expiration for Local Accounts in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87379-enable-disable-password-expiration-local-accounts-windows-10-a.html)
- [How to Change Maximum and Minimum Password Age for Local Accounts in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87386-change-maximum-minimum-password-age-local-accounts-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Sorry, but it's about account expiration, not password expiration. Those are different things...

Comment: So what is the question? You asked: "Is it possible to set **password expiration date** for one local account in Windows?"

Comment: The question is about password expiration. Your answer is about account expiration. Different things.

Comment: My answer was for the only date-expiration property possible for an account. I rewrote my answer for password expiration only.